# Centos7 slave zones doesn't query master for zone file

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

[This is my named.conf.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gygT.png) [These are zones on 192.168.2.194.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN1TV.png)

Also, 192.168.2.194 can successfully query zone files from centos 7 master zones.

Comment: `named.conf` is a text file, provide it (the relevant parts) as text in your question, do not use images. Same for the zones. Your question is also not very clear, please state what test you do with which command, and what results do you get. `dig` is a good DNS troubleshooting tool, or you can also look at your logfiles.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I configure virtual box machines and don't want to waste time retyping all what's depicted.

Comment: I need my `centos7` `named` query zone files from the master, as described as default behavior in all tutorials. What output of `dig` do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 trying of find problem from `journal` logs, `journal` brought me it. [Problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLEGu.png)

I needed to run `chmod o+w slaves`.